# Why the default authentication Hadoop is unsecured？

Tags: hadoop

I saw some article says that the default authentication Hadoop is unsecured , as "In the default authentication Hadoop and all machines in the cluster believe every user credentials presented.". for example in the article  https://blog.eduonix.com/bigdata-and-hadoop/learn-secure-hadoop-cluster-using-kerberos-part-1/, I still can not understand  why this would happens , doesn't the Linux OS is not capable of validating the  credentials,? is there anyone can provide a detail example to explain it ?

Comment: Well, Hadoop can technically run on any OS. Not sure why it'd need to rely exclusively on Linux user groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it did use "Linux OS" way of validating credentials, there's no guarantees that every node in the system has the same credentials without tools external to the Hadoop project. Out of the box with access controls enabled, then `HADOOP_USER_NAME` environment variable is checked to anything you access, but it's just a plain string and easily overridden.

[ACLs do work similarly to the Unix users and groups](https://hortonworks.com/blog/hdfs-acls-fine-grained-permissions-hdfs-files-hadoop/), but even then, a "bob" user on my machine shouldn't be seen the same as any other machine, even if I login to that account on them.

That's where external systems of LDAP/AD/Kerberos come into play, which were used before Hadoop security became a major concern. And those allow centralized user & access management outside of just Hadoop

> the theory is that it is much easier to effectively secure a small set of limited-use machines, rather than a large set of heterogeneous, multipurpose servers and workstations over which the administrator may have little control.

https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch11_04.htm

Comment: "a "bob" user on my machine shouldn't be seen the same as any other machine, even if I login to that account on them." ， however a "bob" user in your machine cannon login the machines host the Hadoop cluster ,so you still cannot destroy the Hadoop cluster.

Comment: That's one reason why you'd use Kerberos with SSH

Comment: Sorry for my junior knowledge on Hadoop sSecurity ,I means if the "bob" user in your machine  cannot destroy the Hadoop cluster., then it is still securely.  so why says  that the default authentication Hadoop is unsecured?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you just start a namenode and datanode, that's a fully working Hadoop environment. If it were secure by default, I'd need a certificate authority and proper firewall rules for networking and key-pairs, etc before even I could start Hadoop

Comment: Just because I can accidently remove all files doesn't make a software product insecure. Any Oracle database admin can go delete the information table, yet Oracle is still "secure".... What you're talking about is trust, not security

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. I mean if the "default authentication Hadoop is unsecured" , can you kindly help to give a detail example to explain why it is not unsecured?  such as a malicious user can destroy the Hadoop cluster . As my understanding, if bob says he is bob , it must be bob, as the OS can confirms it, otherwise the OS wouldn't let he login because a fake bob cannot know the password for the bob.

Comment: Hadoop is unsecured by default because all users can do literally anything. There's no passwords, no TLS, no keypairs. It's all plaintext traffic... Based on your response, any system could be spoofed. If someone logs into your bank pretending to be you, surely it's you, and not fraudulent?

Comment: And you would combine system login, network login, and password protected SSH keys with 2FA so you can better trust who is accessing what systems.

Comment: "Hadoop is unsecured by default because all users can do literally anything. There's no passwords, no TLS, no keypairs"? ??,based on my understanding, if you want to destroy the Hadoop cluster , you must login the Machines hosts the Hadoop firstly, such as you must login the  name node , however if you have no password for name node, how can you login name node? If you even cannot login the name node, how can you destroy the Hadoop cluster?  do you mean any user who can login the name node can destroy the Hadoop cluster?

Comment: The namenode still has users and groups. It still has an OS. But no, you can issue a `rm` command to the namenode from any machine capable of running a Hadoop client (which is what I mean by all users)

Comment: okay, however before issuing a rm command to the namenode , the Hadoop client must connects to the name node firstly , right? and there is no authentication when Hadoop client connect to the name node by default ?

Comment: No, there is not